# Происхождение слова "гой" (изгой)

Tags: этимология

Слышал о том,  что забытое старорусское слово "гой" происходит от ещё более забытого "го", обозначающего некую энергию, наподобие китайского "ци". Отсюда - голова - ловит го, глаголить - гласом го лить... город,  гора,  гордость и т. д.  Английское go - идти.

Как видно, многие современные слова сохранили след этого слова,  но конкретной информации мне найти не удаётся.

Что вы думаете по поводу происхождения слова "гой"? А также встречалось ли вам в литературе "го" как самостоятельное слово?

Comment: Думаю, тут поможет знаменитый постсоветский лингвист Задорнов.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть здесь мнение не мение известного знатока русского языка и, как выяснилось, культуры - alexsms... Увы, не получилось.

Comment: С каких пор Задорнов стал лингвистом?

Comment: 1) https://toldot.com/urava/ask/urava_1741.html ; 2) https://toldot.com/urava/ask/urava_5566.html ; 3) https://toldot.com/urava/ask/urava_7142.html ; 4) https://toldot.com/urava/ask/urava_9369.html .

Answer (score 2):

Всё, что вы слышали про «старорусское» слово *го(й)*, про некую энергию *го*, скорее всего, не имеет никакой связи с тем, что было на самом деле. Английское *go* совершенно тут точно ни при чем!

Гораздо более разумно выглядит предположение, что *изгой* — слово, образованное от глагола *изжити* 'прожить, изжить, выжить' (РЭС, вып. 11, сс. 100-101).

Слово *гой* 'мир, спокойствие' того же корня, что и *изгой* (вопреки ответу Галины Аванесовой), и, вероятно, является дериватом (=производным) от глагола *жить* (прасл. *жити).

Насчет *го* как отдельного слова: есть такое восклицание, фиксируемое в диалектах, звучащее как показатель удивления. Вполне возможно, что какой-нибудь автор использовал его и в своем тексте.

Comment: Это более походит на правду,  чем еврейское происхождение,  ибо былинное - "ой, ты гой еси, добрый молодец" и есенинское -" гой ты, Русь моя, родная, хаты - в ризах образа", лично моё сознание направляет к словянским корням.

Comment: @Сашка-дурак ну, еврейское-то слово есть, но только совершенно не в том значении, какое вы имели в виду. Кстати, у Есенина «гой» уже скорее всего утратило тот старый смысл, который содержится в формуле «гой еси» (она приблизительно похожа на «будь здоров»).

Comment: Мне думается - "живая есть".

Comment: У Преображенского "гой" - заздравный клич.

Answer (score 0):

Литературы мною прочитано много-премного: "го" только встречалось только в [и-го-го](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%BE&all=x).

*Гой* и *изгой* даже не однокоренные - так, случайное созвучие.

[**Гой**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B9) (ивр. ‏גוי‏‎, мн.число גויים *гойи́м*), в современных иврите и идише — это стандартное выражение в Танахе для «народа», включая евреев. В другом значении — это обозначение язычника (неиудея в иудаизме, встречается в обиходной речи в значении «иноверец»).

**[Изгой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9)** (от *из-жити*, праславянский корень *go-i/gi* 'жить', гоити — «живить», ср. былинную формулу *гой еси*) — древнерусский социальный термин, означавший человека, выпавшего («выжитого») из своей социальной среды.

---

Некие [размышления на полях](https://www.evrey.com/sitep/askrabbi1/q.php?q=otvet/q3620.htm), небезынтересные:

> Русское слово *изгой*. Не обозначает ли оно слово - *гой*? *Из гоев*?
>   Ведь известно, что в русском языке полно слов из латинского,
>   английского, тюркских и т. д. языков!

А народ и отвечает (пунктуация авторская):

> Со всей определенностью говорить об этимологии русского слова «изгой»
>   — не берусь. Однако предложенную Вами версию нахожу интересной и не
>   лишенной некоторого смысла.
>
> Во всяком случае, в значениях этого слова в русском языке и слова
>   «гой» в разговорном, бытовом идише действительно есть очевидное
>   сходство.
>
> «Изгоем» называют человека, который утратил прежний (допустим,
>   социальный) статус, стал, с точки зрения общества, которому
>   принадлежал (или мог принадлежать по факту рождения) — «чужим»,
>   «другим».
>
> Европейские евреи, разговаривая в быту на языке идиш, достаточно часто
>   использовали, а иногда и теперь используют, ивритское слово «гой» в
>   значении — «нееврей», «чужой», «иной».
>
> Причем, никакой оценки (ни позитивной, ни негативной) это слово в себе
>   не содержит. Само по себе оно — нейтрально и отчасти может считаться
>   синонимом слова «человек». И тогда становится очевидным, что его
>   «окраска» зависит от контекста, в котором оно произносится.
>
> Впрочем, в переводе с иврита слово «гой» означает — «народ» (любой). В
>   том числе — и еврейский.
>
> Именно в этом значении («еврейский народ») оно довольно часто
>   употребляется в наших первоисточниках.
>
> ---

Ещё подсказчик нам

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9&all=x)

> **ИЗГОЙ**, -я; ***м.*** **1.** В Древней Руси: человек, вышедший из своего прежнего социального состояния (выкупившийся на свободу холоп,
>   разорившийся купец, неграмотный сын священника, князь, потерявший
>   родовое старшинство, и т. п.). **2.** Человек, стоящий вне какой-л.
>   среды, общества, отвергнутый ими; отверженный, отщепенец. Быть изгоем
>   в какой-л. среде.

---

> **1. ГОЙ, *межд*.** (обычно со сл.: еси и местоим. 2 л.). *Нар.-поэт.* Употр. при приветствии, обращении. * *Ой ты гой еси, Волга, мать
>   родная!* (Пушкин).
>
> **2.** **ГОЙ**, -я; ***м.*** [ивр. goi - народ] **1.** В иудаизме: о человеке, не исповедующем иудаизм; язычник. **2.** О человеке, который
>   по вере или национальности не принадлежит к евреям; чужой.
>
> ---

Есть "го", в правильном направлении идёте, товарищ!

> **ГО** [гэо], *нескл., ж.* (сокр.: гражданская оборона)
>
> **ГО**, ***неизм.; ж.*** [япон.] Игра специальными фишками (камнями) на квадратной доске, пересечённой горизонтальными и вертикальными
>   линиями, напоминающая шашки.

Comment: У евреев может быть своё слово,  у славян - своё.  Схожесть их звучания никак не доказывает происхождение из иврита, - семантика не та.

Comment: А я и не говорю о происхождении славянского *изгой* от ивритского *гой*.

Comment: @Сашка-дурак будьте добры, выражайте мысли конкретней.

Comment: Воспроизвожу шапку вороса, побуквенно: ***Происхождение слова “гой” (изгой)***.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю , что это по принципу жить по КОНу (в КОНе) и ЗАКОНу (За КОНом).
Так же и Гой и ИзГой. Уверен.
Что-то типа свой и не свой. Пришлый и Пошлый.

Comment: 1) https://toldot.com/urava/ask/urava_1741.html ; 2) https://toldot.com/urava/ask/urava_5566.html ; 3) https://toldot.com/urava/ask/urava_7142.html ; 4) https://toldot.com/urava/ask/urava_9369.html ;

Answer (score -1):

гоить, гою, гоишь, обл. сев.~
вост. давать жить, устроить,
приютить; грй! заздравный клич.
(Былинн. «го еси, удало добры
молодец!»); гойны видный, краси-
вый (ДСл. 1, 376); угоить, за
гбит заживить; загоитьс зажить
( ране).
мр. гий, Р. го целебное сред-
спгво; гоит исцелять; заживлять;
гий! воскл. др. гоит живить, го
рах, fides, amicitia; гойны abun-
dans; гойник; гойл уепокоенге,
укреплсние ; изго потерявший зва-
ние, exsors. [«Изго трои.: попо
сы грамот н умеет , холо
 холопств выкупится, купе
одолжает, a ce и четверто из
гоиств и себ приложит: ащ
княз осиротеет». Срезн. М. 1,
1052).] б. гоы воспитываю, от-
кармливаю; гое откормленный.
СЛ. goj м., goja ж. уход; gojiti
ухаживать. с. rôj воспитание, вос-
кормление; го]ит лелеять, вскар-
мливать, откармливать; rôjaH взле-
леянный, вскормленный. ч. hojiti
исцелять; -se заживать; hojny
изобильный, богатый. п. goic за-
онтвлять (рану), излечивать. вл.
hojic тж. нл. gojis тж.
— Перегласов. жить . сскр.
gâyas дом и двор, хозяйство
(Уленбек, AiW. 77). зенд. gayö
жизнь, время жизни. лит. gojùs
легко исцеляющий.—сскр. jivati
живеть. зенд. *ivaiti тж. и др.
лит. gyti выздоравливатЬу оживать;
gydyti лечить. лтш. dseedét тж.
(MEW. 64. Matzenauer, LF. 11,
186. BEW. 319). Яги (АЯ. 13,
297 и сл.) связывае изго с
иждит (изжити): та ка иж
дит значи аалаvйv, т изго
може означать: 1. абстрактное—
аала.щ, όαπάνηΰις издержки. 2.
лицо: илиактивн. ααπανηρόςοαιοιίϊαί
средства, ил пассивн. άαπανηρός
требующий гшдержек. Неверн
сравнени с герм. friedlos, дрсев.
fridhlos. Следуе исходит и
основногозначения: уход,удобство,
уютность. Поэтом наиболе удач
ны переводо дррус. изго о
считае толковани Сергеевича: си-
рота. Ср. выше. Инде. корень:
*gei-, жить, откуд вок. е:жить ,
живо и проч.; вок. о: гоит и
проч. (Вондр. SIGr. 1, 408 идр. м.).
См. жить.
Данный текст из словаря Преображенского. Много орфографических ошибок от того, что копировался он с оригинала, а компьютер сам выдал такую адаптацию под современный язык.  На мой взгляд, в том, что "го" это некая жизненная сила, энергия, словарь, отчасти, подтверждает. И иврит здесь не причём. Я бы выложил фото оригинала, но не знаю, как это делается.

Answer (score -1):

Больше по смыслу и логике подходит что это от еврейского слова ГОЙ в его второстепенном значении. Потому что у славян «изгой» то у евреев «гой». Почти. 
И вполне возможно что из-за веры христианской которая от иудеев изошла то и некоторые слова были подобраны и на русский лад освоены. Примерно как с английским на сегодняшний день.

Comment: Алла, отсутствие лишних запятых, конечно, похвально, но не помешало бы необходимые хоть кое-где поставить.

Comment: Уважаемая Алла! Здесь об этом и не только об этом.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqMvt5PiM40&ab_channel=AlekseiGolovastikov